# struct net_device - no member called 'dev' - but it is there

Tags: linux-device-driver, porting, toolchain, esxi

I am trying to port a driver of an ethernet card from Linux to ESXi. It's going well, but sometimes I find dead ends. Like this one.

One of the errors the compiling is throwing is that the struct net_device has no member 'dev'. This line is triggering the error:

```
static inline struct device *aq_nic_get_dev(struct aq_nic_s *self)
{
        // member ndev is of type struct net_device
        return self->ndev->dev.parent; // the compiles throws the error here
}
```

The `struct net_device` is defined on the Linux header `netdevice.h`:

```
struct net_device
{

    /*
     * This is the first field of the "visible" part of this structure
     * (i.e. as seen by users in the "Space.c" file).  It is the name
     * the interface.
     */
#if defined(__VMKLNX__)
    char            name[VMK_DEVICE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH];
#else /* !defined(__VMKLNX__) */
    char            name[IFNAMSIZ];
#endif /* defined(__VMKLNX__) */
    /* device name hash chain */
    struct hlist_node   name_hlist;

    /*
     *  I/O specific fields
     *  FIXME: Merge these and struct ifmap into one
     */
    unsigned long       mem_end;    /* shared mem end   */
    unsigned long       mem_start;  /* shared mem start */
    unsigned long       base_addr;  /* device I/O address   */
    unsigned int        irq;        /* device IRQ number    */

    /*
     *  Some hardware also needs these fields, but they are not
     *  part of the usual set specified in Space.c.
     */

    unsigned char       if_port;    /* Selectable AUI, TP,..*/
    unsigned char       dma;        /* DMA channel      */

    unsigned long       state;

    struct net_device   *next;

    /* The device initialization function. Called only once. */
    int         (*init)(struct net_device *dev);

    // other stuff below ommited
};
```

Is there anything I am missing? Or the syntax of the call to `dev` might be changed to something more obsolete, since the toolchain uses older versions of gcc and bnutils?

Best,

Francis

Comment: Definition of `struct net_device` type which you show does NOT have `dev` field. It has `init` field, which is a pointer to function, which accepts `dev` as the first argument.

Comment: Oh, that's true. I just don't understand how many functions on other code seem to refer to this member and there's not a problem. Maybe there's a `#define` somewhere and I don't see...

Comment: Hint: Using Elixir web site it's easy to find an indentifier in kernel source code. For the latest `net_device` as a data structure is defined like this: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/netdevice.h#L1774, where https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/netdevice.h#L2023 points to embedded `struct device` in it.